# Adjust polygons by edition (freehand and reshape tools used together)

Tags: qgis, editing, land-classification

I would like to adjust the polygons of my vector file. This vector is a land use classification with classes of vegetation, human uses, etc. So the form of the features classes are so irregular and classification isn't totally correct. So, working only with reshape is so hard to digitalized adjusting, many clicks in order to draw the form feature of image layer perfectly.

Is there possibility to use reshape and freehand together qgis?

Is there any suggestion to make this kind of edition more easy and fast?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably suggest just creating new features but with the **Enable Tracing** tool. You can then draw your polygons freehand and snap it to the vertices of the original feature if need be.

When done, delete the old feature. You can find this tool from the *Advanced Digitizing Toolbar* (which looks like a magnet).