# Reshaping polygon to match other polygon/polyline without using Reshape/Trace or Align to Shape in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, editing

I am trying to edit the geometry of one polygon to match another polygon, same as in this question:

[Snapping polygons while reshaping edges?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141361/snapping-polygons-while-reshaping-edges)

Unfortunately, using the Reshape and Trace editing tools is achingly slow and tedious and I have a bunch of locations spread across a bunch of polygons that require this editing.  I also tried the Enable Tracing tool in QGIS as this thread suggests: [Adjust polygons by edition (freehand and reshape tools used together)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214731/adjust-polygons-by-edition-freehand-and-reshape-tools-used-together) to no avail.

Are there any other approaches that have worked for others to do this efficiently?

Just doing a rough reshape and then clipping or erasing (as suggested in the first thread) gets complicated since the lines intersect in both directions (see image).  I want to align the low-res black polygon to the high-res blue polygon in specific places.

[image]

Comment: You could try to run `simplify geometries` on the high-res polygon.

Comment: Removed tag for ArcGIS Desktop to focus question on QGIS. Feel free to ask a separate question about ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap.

Comment: Is the black polygon a crude match in extent to the blue polygon or is it a crude fill of the hole in the blue polygon?

Comment: They are distinct layers... the black line polygon representing a unique aquatic ecological area and the blue polygon representing a high-res coastline.  Both polygons showing marine areas (the white being land).

Comment: This looks like a datum transformation shift.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the question around. Instead of trying to reshape the simple polygon to match the detailed polygon, create a copy of the detailed polygon and inherit the attributes of the simple polygon using a spatial join.

**QGIS methodology:**

In the Processing Toolbox use the `Vectory general > Join attributes by location` tool using the following parameters:

- Base layer - complex polygon
- Join Layer - simple polygon
- Fields to add - Whichever attributes you want the new dataset to inherit from the simple polygons
- Discard records which could not be joined - checked

Everything else you can leave as default.

Open the attribute table of the new dataset and delete the fields from the original complex polygon.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think the root problem is a transformation shift like mentioned in the comments.

But regarding your question: The easiest way to solve this issue is to use a plugin called `Plain Geometry Editor`. First you have to select the source geometry, copy the WKT string and then select the target geometry and paste it there.

[image: Plain Geometry Editor]